# Spring Boot with REST & JPA, building WAR

Tags: java, maven, jpa, spring-boot, jndi

I am attempting to this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

I have successfully created a Rest Controller and run it through eclipse, and I'm able to get a JSON response in the browser. I have used an Apache Derby embedded database.

What I'd like to do now is run it on my separate Tomcat instance (not embedded), with a JNDI lookup to a MySQL database.

The tutorial mentioned above does not mention JNDI, so I looked [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) instead, which suggested adding

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb
```

to the application.properties file.

I'm pretty sure I have Tomcat set up correctly, as I've used the JNDI lookup before in another app, but attempting to build the WAR using Maven fails:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:comp/env/jdbc/finance'; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
....
```

It seems the tutorials are not complete, or have I missed something? I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: When does the exception occur? `NoInitialContextException` can be thrown by _embedded_ Tomcat as it does not have JNDI enabled by default

Comment: When running mvn package